# Correctly setting LifecycleOwner like first parameter in liveData.observe method in Presenter

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have this method in my Presenter:

```
private void loadAll() {
        LiveData<List<Category>> liveData = categoriesRepository.getAllCategories();
        liveData.observe(getView(), categories -> {
            callView(view -> view.setData(categories));
        });
    }
```

`liveData.observe()` method has 2 parameters.

Second parameter - `@NonNull Observer<T> observer` - everything is clear

But first parameter - `@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner` and here comes my question:

I set `getView()` - because it return my view

`android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements ..., LifecycleOwner`

But `getView()` can return Null and AS say my about it

[image]

How can I fix it? I thick I need hold `LifecycleOwner`  instanse in My `presenter` and not get it from `View`? I jast want realise correctly `liveData.observe` method in my Presenter

Comment: Pass the Fragment not the view.

Comment: what do you mean? View == Fragment (View is 'V' in MVP)

Comment: From the doc [`LiveData#observe(LifecycleOwner owner, Observer<T> observer)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observe) and **Fragment is a LifecycleOwner**. Although I am not sure how you are implementing your getView, it is better if you also include your Presenter code.

Comment: Note that `observe` is used within the Fragment or Activity side while `observerForever` is used within Presenter or ViewModel. So if you are using `observe` in your Presenter you need to change to `observeForever`. The reason is Presenter and ViewModel does not know about Lifecycle.

Comment: I call presenter.attachView(this); from Fragment and In basePresenter I have method 
@Nullable
    protected T getView() {
        return view;
    }

Comment: if I use observeForever how can I remove observe?

Comment: You need to manually remove it after getting the data `removeObserver(Observer<T> observer)`, it is a bit hassle yes though you will not be needing a Fragment instance to use it.